# best way to deal with python pdb flakiness re/stdout?

Tags: python, pdb

If I have a program where `stdout` is redirected, my pdb prompts all go to the redirection, because the library was written to write to `stdout`.

Oftentimes this problem is subtle, causing me to think a program is hanging when it's really waiting for input.

How do people work around this? (Unfortunately, using other debuggers like winpdb is not an option).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that PDB uses Cmd class where by default:

```
use_rawinput = 1
```

It means that Cmd will use `raw_input()` method by default instead of `sys.stdout.readline()` to read from the console . This is done because `raw_input()` supports history (only if `readline` module is loaded) and other useful bits . The only issue is that `raw_input()` does not support redirection, so if you have a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
name=raw_input("Enter your name: ")
```

and run it

```
> python test.py
Enter your name: Alex
```

but, if you run it with output redirection it will stuck

```
> python test.py | tee log
```

this is exactly what PDB uses and why it's stuck as well. As I mentioned `sys.stdin.readline()` supports redirection and if you rewrite the above script using `readline()` it should work.

Back to the original issue all you need to do is to tell Cmd to not use `raw_input()`:

```
Cmd.use_rawinput = 0
```

or

```
pdb = pdb.Pdb()
pdb.use_rawinput=0
pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is just to supplement Ned's, as a way of wrapping the pdb.py `main()` function in a manner which doesn't require copying 40 lines just to change one of them:

```
# sane_pdb.py: launch Pdb with stdout on original
import sys, pdb
def fixed_pdb(Pdb=pdb.Pdb):
    '''make Pdb() tied to original stdout'''
    return Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdb.Pdb = fixed_pdb
    pdb.main()
```

I don't know if it actually works for the questioner's problem, but it does what Ned described...

Answer (score 2):

If you are invoking pdb in code, you can pass your own stdout into the constructor.  `sys.__stdout__` might be a good choice.

If you are invoking pdb from the command line, you could copy the `main()` function from pdb.py into your own sane_pdb.py.  Then change the Pdb() initialization to:

```
pdb = Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__)
```

Then you can invoke sane_pdb.py instead of pdb.py.  It's not awesome that you'd have to copy 40 lines into your own file just to change one of them, but it's an option.